# Android: Unable to highlight pressed item in a recyclerview when addOnItemTouchListener is set to it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The existing code in my application uses a `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` subclass to handle the touches of the recyclerview items. It uses onInterceptTouchEvent method to intercept touches and pass them to a gesture listener for it to take care of the clicks.

The problem arrives when I wanted to highlight the rows recyclerview items when a user clicks on the `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` attribute to the root xml item of the viewholder.

Comment: Could someone tell me the root cause of this behavior?

Comment: I have used the same xml for another recyclerview, without the OnItemTouchListener set, and highlight works well for that case, it's something to do with setting this listener I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an invalid xml atribute

```
<RootViewGroup
    android:background="attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable"true"
   ...
```

You also have to include `clickable` then the other is because accesibility

Comment: I have used the same xml for another recyclerview, without the OnItemTouchListener set, and highlight works well for that case, it's something to do with setting this listener I think.

Comment: Also, I like to know what's happening underneath if you can help me with that.

Comment: Ho! You have to add that in the xml inflated by the adapter and make sure the viewgroup parent of the recycler have a background white usually work

Comment: This is actually the foreground that I've set, and the problem occurs only when the touchListener is set.